# Stop the thread after a particular time

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to stop my thread after particular time. Here with i added my sample code. Any one of the thread takes more than 6 seconds means i want to stop the particular thread. Rest of the thread should not be affected. Do i need to use the Timer or some better way can we achieve? Suppose if i used Timer means do i need to create new timer for each thread and do i need to cancel the timer suppose if the job finished before 6secs?

```
    class MyRunnableThread implements Runnable{

    public static int myCount = 0;
    private String fname = null;
    public MyRunnableThread(String fname){
         this.fname = fname;
    }
    public void run() {

            try{
                //read the content based on text and peforms the operation
                //File.read(this.fname)
                System.out.println("Run method stuff"+ this.fname);
            } catch (Exception iex) {
                System.out.println("Exception in thread: "+iex.getMessage());
            }
    }

}

public class RunMyThread {

    public static void main(String a[]){
        System.out.println("Starting Main Thread...");

        String[] fname = {"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt","file4.txt","file5.txt"};
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            try{
                MyRunnableThread mrt = new MyRunnableThread(fname[i]);
                Thread t = new Thread(mrt);
                System.out.println("Main Thread start "+i);
                t.start();

                //stop the thread support run method takes more than 6seconds
                System.out.println("Main Thread end "+ i );
            } catch (Exception iex){
                System.out.println("Exception in main thread: "+iex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("End of Main Thread...");
    }
}
```

Comment: consider using [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) + [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) as they are designed specially for such purposes and offer large functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User a Timer and a flag to tell the thread to stop:

```
public class MyRunnableThread implements Runnable {

    boolean run = true;

    String fname;

    public MyRunnableThread(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public void setRun(boolean toSet) {
        run = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (run) {
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    private void doStuff() {
//       File.read(fname);
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String[] fname = { "file1.txt", "file2.txt", "file3.txt", "file4.txt", "file5.txt" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            try {

                MyRunnableThread mrt = new MyRunnableThread(fname[i]);
                Thread t = new Thread(mrt);
                t.start();

                final Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                    int i = 6; // Time in seconds

                    public void run() {
                        System.out.println(i--);
                        if (i < 0) {
                            timer.cancel();
                            mrt.setRun(false);
                        }
                    }
                }, 0, 1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Change i to whatever time in seconds you want

Comment: Edited with a better solution

Comment: Is this stops all the thread (which is running more than 6secs) at a single point or it stops each and individual thread? Clearly, Is the timer obj tightly coupled with mrt obj?  mrt and timer are new obj for each and every loop. Will the third obj timer will stop the third obj of mrt?

Comment: There are 6 Threads and 6 Timers, each Thread has his own. But if you launch them at the same time, they will all end at around the same time, after 6 seconds.

Comment: fine. I just changed the condition while (run) to while(true) , how do i stop the thread process. t.stop or t.destroy wont help. In my doStuff method somewhere it get hanged means i want to cancel or stop the thread

Comment: You changed the very line that allows you to stop it. Put back "while(run)" and then use the method setRun(false) like in my example !

Comment: Sorry for the delay reply. t.stop itself worked fine when i changed the condition as while(true).

Comment: I think you did not really understand my code then :) I did not use t.stop(), but if it works for you... If your problem is resolved, please mark one answer as "Accepted". Cheers

Answer (score 1):

One thought would be you have an ArrayList containing all your threads.

Then you make each thread have an extra field (Timestamp started)

Then you have a timer looping through the Arraylist and stopping the threads where started > 6 seconds ago

Answer (score 0):

Well.. there're a lot of ways to do it, I'll explain you one of those.

You can create a custom class that `extends Thread` and then implement the method `run()` and `CancelCurrentThread()`, your run will start the `Thread` and `CancelCurrentThread()` will stop it ignoring the exceptions.

Then your code should look like :

```
mCustomThread thread = new mCustomThread(parametres_if_you_need);
thread.start(); //Start the Thread
thread.join(6000);  //Adding 6 seconds
//You can detect if the 6 seconds have passed or not for example using a timer, then if it joins on this if condition you can call
thread.CancelCurrentThread();
```

Comment: I am not clear about your reply, can you provide the samples?