# Stop a thread running in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch, java-threads

I have a Spring batch application, that uses partition to run some threads.
the problem is, I need to stop my thread if it reaches a certain time.

I don't know how to do that.
I have a partitioner step

```
@Bean
public Step partitionerStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("PARTITIONER_STEP")
            .partitioner("SLAVE_STEP", partitioner())
            .step(stepConcederPerfilNormal())
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}
```

First I thought I could stop my thread using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor but isn't work as I thought

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
    executor.setCorePoolSize(50);
    executor.setAllowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
    return executor;
}
```

Just to fix it. I need to stop my thread if it's running for 1H30M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Batch does not create or manage threads, it delegates that to a `TaskExecutor`.

> I need to stop my thread if it's running for 1H30M

The following might help: [Stop the thread after a particular time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36151503/stop-the-thread-after-a-particular-time)